# How to skip 'Asking Permission step' in shopify API integration with PHP

Tags: php, shopify

I am new at `API` integration.

I am trying to fetch product list from my shopify store.

It's working fine. But the problem is when I run my script it ask me for username and password of store. When I enters it, it shows list.

I want to skip this step as I am going to run this script on server.

How to achieve this. I searched their forum but no luck.

Please Help.

Comment: Ankit please follow below steps and check once. If worked then mark and up-vote the answer for others help. If not then please check the link for further details. thanks.

Comment: if you are using the php code api, this not ask for permission, you only need the api keys which one work with curl. maybe you have to read this [private-app-setup](https://docs.shopify.com/api/guides/introduction/creating-a-private-app#setup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow below steps:-

1. From your `Shopify admin`, click `Settings`, then click `Online Store`
2. In the Storefront password section, uncheck the `Password protect your storefront option`
3. click on save.

Now access store data through app without any password verification step. Thanks.

For more details:- https://docs.shopify.com/manual/intro-to-shopify/initial-setup

Comment: Thank you Anant for responding, but problem is that when I access product list via API it asks me credentials, I want to solve that, Your solution is perfect but its for accessing with direct url not through API, correct me if I am wrong, I want for API.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, Its working now, but this is case for private app or public app?? I think its for private app.